# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: watin

w => w.ClassName == "Button" && new WinButton(w.Hwnd).Title == "OK"

I am using a class that clicks 'OK' on the all dialog windows that opens while testing a website on Watin. But this line gives an error of lambda expression cannot be converted to type string because it is not a delegate type.

I have used using System.Linq and still does not work

Please help me out!

The whole code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using WatiN.Core;
using SCO.Automated.Testing.Service;
using WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers;
using WatiN.Core.Native.Windows;
using WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer;


namespace SCO.Automated.Testing.Service
{

    public class OKDialogHandler : BaseDialogHandler
    {
        public override bool HandleDialog(Window window)
        {
            var button = GetOKButton(window);
            if (button != null)
            {
                button.Click();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override bool CanHandleDialog(Window window)
        {
            return GetOKButton(window) != null;
        }

        private WinButton GetOKButton(Window window)
        {
            var windowButton = new WindowsEnumerator().GetChildWindows(window.Hwnd, w => w.ClassName == "Button" && new WinButton(w.Hwnd).Title == "OK").FirstOrDefault();
        if (windowButton == null)
            return null;
        else
            return new WinButton(windowButton.Hwnd);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a complete line of source code. Please post the context around the lambda expression.

Answer (score 2):

Given [the code here](http://watin.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/watin/trunk/src/Core/Native/Windows/WindowsEnumerator.cs?revision=1169&view=markup), that looks fine to me.

Is it possible that you're using an older version of WatiN which doesn't have that overload? If you look in `WindowsEnumerator` in Reflector, do you see this overload?

```
public IList<Window> GetChildWindows(IntPtr hwnd,
                                     WindowEnumConstraint constraint)
```

Comment: @Jon: Im not sure how exactly to look in WindowsEnumerator

Comment: @Jasjit: Do you have Reflector installed? If not, that's the first thing to get. http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/

Comment: @Jasjit: Okay, so now open the relevant WatiN DLL and look for WindowsEnumerator. See what's available.

Comment: @Jon: ok yes im looking at the WindowsEnumerator in Reflector. So I should change the code with the one you gave ?

Comment: @Jasjit: No, you should *look* for that method signature. If you can't find it, you probably need a newer version of WatiN.

Comment: @Jon: no actually it is not there in the code it was a mistake, which version of watin did you send the code from ?

Comment: @Jasjit: I was looking in source control - follow the link. See whether the latest stable version has it.